# how to write data from a table row when a table row is clicked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

To explain further... I have an asp.net table and textbox. There are multiple rows in the table. Right now, I have some jquery code that allows users to click on rows and it will find a link in the row and take the user to that url. Here is my code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var selected = null;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#<%=orders_data.ClientID%>").find("tr").click(function () {
                    $(selected).removeClass("selected");
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                    selected = this;
                });

                $("#<%=orders_data.ClientID%>").find("tr").click(function () {
                    var href = $(this).find("a");
                    href.attr("target", "_blank");
                    window.open(href.attr("href"))
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Now, instead of finding the a tag and opening the link, how can I make jquery take data from the selected row in the table "orders_data" and write this data in a textbox? Let me know if I need to further clarify anything!

Comment: +1 for the clear question, formatting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using this

```
$('#<%=orders_data.ClientID%> td').click(function(){

   var row_index = $(this).parent().index();
    alert(row_index);
   var col_index = $(this).index();
    alert(col_index);
    $tr=$(this).parent();
    alert($tr);
    var data1=$tr.find("td").eq(1).html();
    var data1=$tr.find("td").eq(1).html();
    alert(data1);
    $('#<%=asp.net_textID%>"').val(data2);
});
```

**Logic**

1. get the current td using `$(this)`.
2. get the current td's parent ie tr using `$(this).parent()`.
3. find the td using the index.

Live demo at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KSyB8/86/)

Comment: Thanks VeeKayBee, this lets me get the data I want. Now I'm trying to figure out how to change the textbox.text property to this data. But this is a great start :)

Comment: @baba sorry forget to update the answer as what i did in the demo. Please check the updated answer and if you feels that its works for you kindly accept as answer.

Comment: I was trying something like this... $('#textbox').val(data1); Thanks for the help VeeKayBee!

Comment: This works great, but how could I get this to work with an asp.net table and an asp.net textbox?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34010/discussion-between-veekaybee-and-baba)